# Net exports term in aggregate expenditure

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, balance-of-trade, aggregate-production

This might be a basic question, which I don't yet understand. The aggregate expenditure (i.e., in my understanding, the total amount of inflation factored (i.e. real) money spent in the economy by its participants) can be expressed as: $$Y = C+I+G+X-M$$

where $X$ is exports and $M$ is imports. Why isn't it $Y = C+I+G+M-X$? Aren't we spending in imports while having a cash flow by exports, i.e. effectivly reducing our expenditures at the end of the day?

We can go through the [logic that GDP](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9560/why-are-imports-subtracted-from-gdp?noredirect=1&lq=1) plus the imports (total goods) go to consumption, investment, government spending and exports. Then use GDP=expenditure and arrive to the answer. I don't want to go by that route but instead to focus on real money spent. We spend on imports and receive money on exports, i.e. opposite of the formula above.

Comment: This question was asked already.  Please see : https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9560/why-are-imports-subtracted-from-gdp/9563

Comment: @MikeJ  that post would answer my question if look at from the side of GDP, i.e. goods produced in the economy. But I want to look it from the side of expenditure, i.e. real money spent in the economy by its members. I don't want to use GDP=expenditure logic to arrive to the right conclusion.

Comment: @Giskard thanks! see my above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you are adding up is not the Gross Domestic **Product**, rather something like the Gross Domestic Expenditure.
$$
C+I+G+X-M = Y = C+I+G+M-X
$$
could only possibly hold if $M - X = 0$, that is if the trade balance was zero. If this is not true, e.g., if $M - X > 0$ than a country's gross expenditure is larger than its production, so counting these things will not both sum up to $Y$.